# Mocking external services in API with Codeception

Tags: codeception

I have API end point:

> [GET] /car/:carId

which is actually a controller action ( CarController::car( $carId ) ):

```
public function car( $cardId )
{
        $carId = (int) \Yii::$app->request->get( 'car_id' );

        if ( empty( $carId ) ) {
            throw new \yii\web\BadRequestHttpException( 'Wrong car id. It must be integer, greater than 0' );
        }

        $externalVinService = new externalVinService();

        $vinNumberResponseData = $externalVinService->getCarVinNumber( $carId );

        if ( $vinNumberResponseData['code'] !== 200 ) {
            \Yii::$app->response->statusCode = $vinNumberResponseData['code'];
            return [ 'message' => 'Something is wrong with car VIN external service' ];
        }

        $carModel = new carModel( $cardId );

        $carData = $carModel->getCarData();

        $carData['vin'] = $vinNumberResponseData['data']['vin'];

        \Yii::$app->response->statusCode = 200;

        return $carData;
}
```

I want to write functional test that test this controller action, e.g.:

```
$I->wantTo( 'check if I get correct car data' );
$I->sendGET( '/car/10' );
$I->seeResponseCodeIs( 200 );
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
// Asserting response data, etc
//...
//...
```

Can I mock externalVinService class somehow? It would not be a problem while working with Unit tests, but in my scenario I can't find 
an easy way to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [AspectMock](https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock).

One of the features is: `Create test doubles for class methods called anywhere.`

It works if you use a framework module (e.g. Yii2) module but doesn't work with PhpBrowser or WebDriver.